# Why I am getting a negative loss and negative validation loss in my model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am training a variational autoencoder using USPS dataset of shape (7291, 16, 16). Below is my code snipet. I also tried the same code snipet on MNIST dataset of shape (60000,28,28) and everything seems to work fine. Both are gray scale images. I can figure out why I am getting the a negative value for training loss and validation loss for USPS dataset. The code execution is quite straight forwards, The only changes from MNIST model is `mnist.load_data()` to `usps.load_data()`.

I also have also tried reducing the number of layers in both the encoder and decoder network but the result for the USPS model appears the same. I can figure out what exactly I am getting wrong. please I need your assistance to understand the reason for the negative values.

```
!pip install extra_keras_datasets
#######################################
from extra_keras_datasets import usps
import keras
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, Input, Flatten, Dense, Lambda, Reshape
#from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Model
from keras.datasets import mnist
import tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load MNIST
# (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = usps.load_data()

#Normalize and reshape ============

#Norm.
x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
x_train = x_train / 255
x_test = x_test / 255

# Reshape 
img_width  = x_train.shape[1]
img_height = x_train.shape[2]
num_channels = 1 #MNIST --> grey scale so 1 channel
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_height, img_width, num_channels)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_height, img_width, num_channels)
input_shape = (img_height, img_width, num_channels)
# ========================

# BUILD THE MODEL

# # ================= #############
# # Encoder
#Let us define 4 conv2D, flatten and then dense
# # ================= ############

latent_dim = 2 # Number of latent dim parameters

#Create the model
input_img = Input(shape=input_shape, name='encoder_input')
x = Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(input_img)
x = Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu',strides=(2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
conv_shape = K.int_shape(x) #Shape of conv to be provided to decoder
print(conv_shape)
#Flatten
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)

# Two outputs, for latent mean and log variance (std. dev.)
#Use these to sample random variables in latent space to which inputs are mapped. 
z_mu = Dense(latent_dim, name='latent_mu')(x)   #Mean values of encoded input
z_sigma = Dense(latent_dim, name='latent_sigma')(x)  #Std dev. (variance) of encoded input


#REPARAMETERIZATION TRICK
# Define sampling function to sample from the distribution
# Reparameterize sample based on the process defined by Gunderson and Huang
# into the shape of: mu + sigma squared x eps
#This is to allow gradient descent to allow for gradient estimation accurately. 
def sample_z(args):
  z_mu, z_sigma = args
  eps = K.random_normal(shape=(K.shape(z_mu)[0], K.int_shape(z_mu)[1]))
  return z_mu + K.exp(z_sigma / 2) * eps

# sample vector from the latent distribution
# z is the labda custom layer we are adding for gradient descent calculations
  # using mu and variance (sigma)
z = Lambda(sample_z, output_shape=(latent_dim, ), name='z')([z_mu, z_sigma])

#Z (lambda layer) will be the last layer in the encoder.
# Define and summarize encoder model.
encoder = Model(input_img, [z_mu, z_sigma, z], name='encoder')
print(encoder.summary())
```

Decoder

```
x = Dense(conv_shape[1]*conv_shape[2]*conv_shape[3], activation='relu')(decoder_input)
# reshape to the shape of last conv. layer in the encoder, so we can 
x = Reshape((conv_shape[1], conv_shape[2], conv_shape[3]))(x)
# upscale (conv2D transpose) back to original shape
# use Conv2DTranspose to reverse the conv layers defined in the encoder
x = Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu',strides=(2, 2))(x)
#Can add more conv2DTranspose layers, if desired. 
#Using sigmoid activation
x = Conv2DTranspose(num_channels, 3, padding='same', activation='sigmoid', name='decoder_output')(x)

# Define and summarize decoder model
decoder = Model(decoder_input, x, name='decoder')
# apply the decoder to the latent sample 
z_decoded = decoder(z)
decoder.summary()
```

custom loss and model fitting

```
#VAE is trained using two loss functions reconstruction loss and KL divergence
#Let us add a class to define a custom layer with loss
class CustomLayer(keras.layers.Layer):

    def vae_loss(self, x, z_decoded):
        x = K.flatten(x)
        z_decoded = K.flatten(z_decoded)
        
        # Reconstruction loss (as we used sigmoid activation we can use binarycrossentropy)
        recon_loss = keras.metrics.binary_crossentropy(x, z_decoded)
        
        # KL divergence
        kl_loss = -5e-4 * K.mean(1 + z_sigma - K.square(z_mu) - K.exp(z_sigma), axis=-1)
        return K.mean(recon_loss + kl_loss)

    # add custom loss to the class
    def call(self, inputs):
        x = inputs[0]
        z_decoded = inputs[1]
        loss = self.vae_loss(x, z_decoded)
        self.add_loss(loss, inputs=inputs)
        return x

# apply the custom loss to the input images and the decoded latent distribution sample
y = CustomLayer()([input_img, z_decoded])
# y is basically the original image after encoding input img to mu, sigma, z
# and decoding sampled z values.
#This will be used as output for vae

# =================
# VAE 
# =================
vae = Model(input_img, y, name='vae')

# Compile VAE
vae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=None)
vae.summary()

# Train autoencoder
vae.fit(x_train, None, epochs = 10, batch_size = 32, validation_split = 0.2)
```

Here is my training History.

```
5832/5832 [==============================] - 5s 928us/sample - loss: 0.0345 - val_loss: -0.0278
Epoch 2/10
5832/5832 [==============================] - 4s 740us/sample - loss: -0.0301 - val_loss: -0.0292
Epoch 3/10
5832/5832 [==============================] - 4s 746us/sample - loss: -0.0307 - val_loss: -0.0293
Epoch 4/10
5832/5832 [==============================] - 4s 751us/sample - loss: -0.0307 - val_loss: -0.0294
Epoch 5/10
5832/5832 [==============================] - 4s 753us/sample - loss: -0.0307 - val_loss: -0.0294
Epoch 6/10
5832/5832 [==============================] - 4s 746us/sample - loss: -0.0307 - val_loss: -0.0294
Epoch 7/10
5832/5832 [==============================] - 4s 750us/sample - loss: -0.0307 - val_loss: -0.0294
Epoch 8/10
5832/5832 [==============================] - 4s 742us/sample - loss: -0.0307 - val_loss: -0.0294
Epoch 9/10
5832/5832 [==============================] - 4s 751us/sample - loss: -0.0307 - val_loss: -0.0294
Epoch 10/10
5832/5832 [==============================] - 4s 748us/sample - loss: -0.0307 - val_loss: -0.0294
```

Comment: Hi, Did you find the problem? I encounter with a similar problem and my loss is negative. Thanks